# Difference between read(byte[] b, int off, int len) and read(byte [] b)

Tags: java, io

In our project sometimes when we use `InputStream.read(byte[] b)` method, there is some error.
When we use

```
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
int len = -1;
while ((len = io.read(b, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
    response.getOutputStream().write(b, 0, len);
}
```

then it goes well.

I found the source code, which is amazing

```
public int read(byte b[]) throws IOException {
    return read(b, 0, b.length);
}
```

Inside `read` method, it calls `read(b, 0, b.length)`. In our project, `b.length` equals `1024`, so why do we get the error?

Does anybody know the difference between these two methods?
Thanks

Comment: And what kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as `read(byte[])` calls `read(byte[], int, int)`, there *is* no difference. The first is just a shorter way of doing the read. There must obviously be something else that is wrong, such as wrong input parameters or something of the like.

EDIT:
Like Zenzen said, what error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for your error is that there are not 1024 bytes available to read from the InputStream. Notice that from your example

```
read(b, 0, b.length);
```

is safely checking the number of bytes available to read from the stream, where as the static 1024 byte read you referenced

```
read(b, 0, 1024)
```

is not taking this precaution.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The code failed when they tried using the `read(byte[])` method, but worked when they replaced that to directly use the `read(byte[], int, int)` method.

Comment: If there aren't 1024 bytes available, the read will just get what's there.  (That's why `read` returns an int rather than a boolean: so it can return *how much* it read).  And, the args to `read(b, 0, b.length)` have nothing to do with how much is available in the stream -- they're specifying a region in the *array*.  If the array length is 1024 in both cases (and the OP says it is), the two calls are exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated, an exception and stack trace would be very helpful.

Read can return a length of zero.  Is it possible that your OutputStream does not support writes of length 0 ?  The JavaDocs for OutputStream don't indicate a restriction, but it seems possible that a subclass could have such a boundary error.